# Can't make new partitions on my dual booted hard disk

Tags: partitioning

I can't make partitions on ubuntu and also on windows. When I am going to create another partition it says "you can't create 4 primary partitions". I tried gparted but it didn't let me to create a partition. My hard disk is 500gb.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an "extended partition" as the fourth partition. This partition may span about the whole remaining of your disk. Inside this extended partition you can then create many logical partitions. (The extended partition itselft cannot be used for filesystems, it is just a container for further partitions.)